# Looking for input on picking an algorithm that parses a mailbox

Tags: c++, regex, stl

The idea is to look for urls in emails of an entire mailbox. There are at least 20 urls to look for and the amount of email bodies could be 10mb or 100 GB  collectively.

I planned to use the regular expressions to look for match's as many times as there are urls on as many email bodies that exist, like 20 regex_match calls on 1 string.

The application is written in C++ and I entinded to use the stl::regex_match and favor speed over memory usage.

I think my approach can be improved (linear search/for loop on email body string calling regex_match), but I don't have much experience on string parsing unknown text at this scale. Do you have suggestion on how to implement this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unrelated but important (I will come to the answer in a while): If you have access to multiple machines, scale *out*: use Mapreduce or spark.

You can check for the URLs in the mails in parallel, and thus your problem naturally fits in the distributed framework.

For example, if you end up using map reduce, just feed one mail per mapper, and you are done.

Back to your question, the *fastest* approach to solve this depends on the kind of dataset that we are dealing with here (Are there lots of URLs? Only a few? Lots of URLs but only a few match the 20?)

Thus, one could think of several strategies.

---

Yes, you can use regex. There are classical links that you would find for this, for example [this](http://flanders.co.nz/2009/11/08/a-good-url-regular-expression-repost/).

If the set of URLs that you have is fixed, you can create a trivial single regex out of them, and call the library.

A single call to a regex must be faster than 20 calls to string matching functions.

As a final tweak if you are in fact matching 20 strings, match the string that you expect to be present most of the times first.

---

Alternatively, you can use a series of checks.

1. Add a super fast first level check to see if it is a url (presence of a colon at 5th location etc.)
2. If this check is satisfied, call a regex that checks if the string is a URL.
3. If this check is also passed, send the string to the Hashset of the 20 URLs.

You can add more stages to it. Such a machinery will obviously yield gains if there are not many URLs in your data.

Comment: The URLs to check for will be known ahead of time. It sounds like a regex pattern could be constructed consisting of multiple urls and that would reduce the number of calls. Sounds great.